# How to convert timestamp data type in firebase to date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this in my firebase database. 
beginDate: December 25, 2018 at 4:00:00 PM UTC-8. I want this to convert to Date with time.

I tried this and it is not working

{{ (elem.beginDate*1000) | date }}.

I am building an app on Ionic and my template has this code.

From: {{ (elem.beginDate*1000 | date)  }}

which gives an output [object Object]

Comment: when you receive an object OBJECT, try to add a JSON.Stringify(JSONobject). It will help you debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore timestamps aren't returned as numbers.  They're [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) objects.  If you want to convert a Timestamp to a JavaScript Date, use its [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate) method.

Answer (score 0):

First you retrieve the timestamp from firebase then you convert the timestamp to a date with toDate(). You can also use toMillis(). More information on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#returnsnumber

```
db.collection('user').get().then( (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        var time = doc.data().timestamp;
        var date = time.toDate();
        console.log(date);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was getting from Firestore was this:
t {seconds: 1622775600, nanoseconds: 0}

And this is what worked for me to be able to convert it to the date format:

```
  return this.collection.snapshotChanges().
     pipe(map(actions =>{
        return actions.map(item =>{
            const data = item.payload.doc.data() as [myObject];

            data.beginDate = new Date(data.beginDate["seconds"] * 1000);

            const id = item.payload.doc.id;
            return {...data,id};
        })
    }));
```

I hope this is useful to you.